# How to implement spring separated by group singletons

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

how to implement something like this:

```
@MySpringAnnotation(MyEnum.values())
public class Bean {
}
```

and after context initialization I will see for example 5 singletons beans quilified by enum?
I prefer to use Java-based annotation and don't know how to implement multiple context, where configuration classes very similar to each other except the "scope". May there can be some proper way to do that.

Comment: To understand this - Assuming MyEnum has 3 values namely "app", "db" and "cache", you want 3 instances of Bean classes to be created which are qualified by the name "app_bean", "db_bean", "cache_bean" ? If not then elaborate and add more details to explain what you intend to do

Comment: yep, it is exectly what I meant. Actualy I need "app_bean1..n", "db_bean1..n" and "cache_bean1..n". There can be a lot of beans so I want to find a way how to avaoid copy-paste. I did it before using freemarker and xml context, my freemarker template processor created "copy-paste" at runtime. but how to implement it using java-based context configuration without any "huk"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented using custom scope. Create all objects of this scope while initialization and use it in proper way at runtime wiring of beans.